# Why weren't crow's nests safeguarded?

Tags: ships

1. What's the safeguard called, which I marked with a red arrow in the picture underneath?
2. Anyway, why didn't ships in the past have them, to safeguard their crow's nest lookouts? The picture on the right is the *RMS Titanic*, and there doesn't look like one?

Obviously, these ladders are dangerous as someone can fall, especially if a gust blows them off.

> [The Crow’s nest, accessed by climbing up a ladder inside the mast, had a large bell, used to warn the bridge of dangerous ahead, and a telephone so that the officers on bridge could communicate with the lookouts in the crow’s nest.](https://www.titanicpages.com/lookoutsandcrowsnest)

[image]

Comment: Labour was cheap and so was concern for the labourer - this was the dawn of things like the Factories act which started to limit the age of workers and their hours...

Comment: I'm sure that many people did care about Health and Safety. I'm equally sure that they weren't - by and large - the people making the laws. Equally, the people making the laws were not the ones climbing the ladders! This gives some idea of the [history of Health & Safety legislation](https://legislationupdateservice.co.uk/blog/a-brief-history-of-health-and-safety-law/) in the UK

Comment: To understand attitudes, you may want to look at what's required of sailors handling the sails on a large sailing ship.  Climbing to the crow's nest was dead safe by comparison.

Comment: And not just sailors. Any old worker in any industry would tell you that some decades ago safety measures that now are seen as a must were unheard, or if proposed they were seen as a nuisance. I can tell by experience that getting an old bricklayer wear a helmet was that one of the most challenging tasks in the building. I don't imagine a sailor a century ago missing a cage. Some jobs were known to be dangerous, and that was all.

Comment: @jamesqf Why didn't workers do, or care, more about safety back then? For instance, I'd refuse to procreate if life were that bad.

Comment: @sempaiscuba But the people didn't care about Health and Safety to elect politicians who did.

Comment: @PostmodernistAntinatalist Look at [who had the vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffrage#United_Kingdom) and when they got it. The 'property qualification' then in force meant than about 40% of men (and all women) couldn't vote at that time. In general, those who did have the vote weren't going to be the ones climbing the ladders, or doing any of the other dangerous jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you indicate in the left-hand picture is called a [cage](https://simplifiedsafety.com/blog/when-does-a-ladder-require-a-cage/).

In the case of the Titanic, the crow's nest was accessed by a ladder *inside the mast* (as noted in your citation), so the mast itself would have acted as a cage, helping ensure the safety of those climbing the ladder to the crow's nest.

---

As to the wider question of why safety features like cages weren't fitted to most ships at the time the RMS Titanic was built, the reason is simply that [Health and Safety legislation](http://www.hse.gov.uk/legislation/) is a relatively new phenomenon.  The requirements simply didn't exist when Titanic was being designed and built.

You can get an idea of the history and evolution of Health and Safety legislation in the UK from [this infographic](https://legislationupdateservice.co.uk/blog/a-brief-history-of-health-and-safety-law/) on the site of the Legislation Update Service. When viewing this, keep in mind that, as a rule, the people making the laws were not the ones climbing the ladders on ships in rough seas or icy conditions in the North Atlantic!

Comment: You might also find the campaign of Samuel **Plimsoll** to ensure safe loading of vessels of interest. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Plimsoll

Answer (score 5):

Working sailors didn't require many of the modern industrial safeguards, as they were taught to work with "One hand for the ship, and one hand for yourself".  It's a tradition as old as any old sailor.

For example, this is me heading for the main-top aboard the [USCG training vessel Eagle](https://www.uscga.edu/eagle/) during the summer cruise of 1968.

[image]

In more recent years they have adopted the use of tethers for everyone working aloft.